# In SSRS is there a way to use the ID value in SharePoint multivalue lookup field in criteria/filter?

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report with a SharePoint list as its data source.  One of the fields is a multi-value lookup field, and displays as follows:

ID1;#Value1;#ID2;#Value2;#ID3;#Value3

I found a code snippet that removes the ;# from the multiple values, and can now display either a list of IDs (ID1, ID2, ID3) or the actual values (Value1, Value2, Value3).

This same field is also a parameter. If a user-entered value (or value passed from a parent report) is contained within the field's value, results are returned.  In other words if ValueX in (Value1, Value2, Value3), return results.  This works fine.

I am trying to find a way to pass the "ID" portion of that lookup value, instead of the "Value" portion.  So, if IDX in (ID1, ID2, ID3), return results.  So far if I enter a number for the parameter, I don't get any results, even though I see that number when the field displays without modification.

For example - a SharePoint list item displays multivalue lookup field "Fruits" as follows:

1;#Apples;#2;#Bananas;#3;#Grapes [no modification]

Apples, Bananas, Grapes [with code snippet 1]

1, 2, 3 [with code snippet 2]

If I pass 'Bananas', record is returned. If I pass '2', no results.  It seems like I can't really use the Id portion of the lookup values in criteria.  I've tried a group filter to see if the parameter is within the string of Ids but that didn't work.

The piece of the SharePoint query with the parameter just looks like this:

```
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="Fruits" />
        <Value Type="Text">
          <Parameter Name="FruitsParm" />
        </Value>
      </Contains>
```

Is there a way in SSRS to filter based on the ID part of the ID;#Value structure?

Using SQl Server 2008 R2 / Visual Studio 2008 / SharePoint 2010

Comment: I should add FYI - ultimately I am passing the value from a parent report that has SQL datasets, and again it works just fine when passing the 'name' of the fruit (for example).  But can't get the subreport to work on its own in this way, let alone as a subreport.